# Javascript calling php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to write code that writes to a file when a button is clicked. I started to experiment with letting javascript (and jquery) call a .php file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Test Page
</title>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="ST1U" onclick="feedback(this)">I understand</button>
<button id="ST1N" onclick="feedback(this)">I don't understand </button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function feedback(buttonElement){
var bcid= buttonElement.id;
if(bcid==='ST1U'){

    $('#output').load('form.php');
}
else if(bcid==='ST1N'){
    alert("We are sorry you didn't understand")
}}
</script>
```

And in the file 'form.php':

```html
<script type-'text/javascript'>
alert('thank you for your responds')
</script>
```

However, when I click the first button, the php script does not seem to be running, as I do not get the alert message appearing. Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: I don't see a `id="output"` in your code.

Comment: Your code works but you need a <div class-"output"></div>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked jquery to load in output id, where is the element?

Add:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

So your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Test Page
</title>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="ST1U" onclick="feedback(this)">I understand</button>
<button id="ST1N" onclick="feedback(this)">I don't understand </button>
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function feedback(buttonElement){
var bcid= buttonElement.id;
if(bcid==='ST1U'){
    $('#output').load('123.php');
}
else if(bcid==='ST1N'){
    alert("We are sorry you didn't understand");
}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your code adding output id, i have tested it in my local your code working fine, may be you forgot to place the output id..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Test Page
</title>
<head>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button id="ST1U" onclick="feedback(this)">I understand</button>
    <button id="ST1N" onclick="feedback(this)">I don't understand </button>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function feedback(buttonElement){
    var bcid= buttonElement.id;
    if(bcid==='ST1U'){

        $('#output').load('form.php');
    }
    else if(bcid==='ST1N'){
        alert("We are sorry you didn't understand")
    }}
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery instead of javascript....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Test Page
</title>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="ST1U" class="button">I understand</button>
<button id="ST1N"  class="button">I don't understand </button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".button").click(function(){

var bcid= $(this).attr("id");
if(bcid==='ST1U'){

    $('#output').load('form.php');
}
else if(bcid==='ST1N'){
    alert("We are sorry you didn't understand")
}
});

});
```

Comment: There's still no `#output` element.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of feedback(this) , you can use feedback('ST1U') to pass the ID of the element. correct your script tag

Comment: Exactly what's the problem with using `this`? They are getting the `id` from the passed element by `ele.id`.